# Can't install drivers for Alfa AWUS036H

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers

Like another person in this forum, I bought the AWUSO36H 802.11 B/G Long-Range USB Adapter for my computer running latest version of Ubuntu.

Problem is - I can't install the drivers.  I open the CD folder and double click the runsetup but the following message comes back:

```
Archive:  /media/USB Series/autorun.exe
[/media/USB Series/autorun.exe]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/USB Series/autorun.exe or
/media/USB Series/autorun.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/USB Series/autorun.exe.ZIP, period.
```

I downloaded the latest Realtek RTL8187 chipset, rebooted and everything and still can't download the driver.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to install drivers for the AWUS036H.  It should work out of the box for common uses.

If you're talking about monitor mode and injection, I've had mixed experiences with getting that to work.

It seems to work sometimes as long as crypto is disabled.
There also seem to be some bugs with proper card initialization and a total lack of ability to use hostapd on 3.x kernels with stock drivers.